# check if click is outside of Element - on removed item

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I tried the jquery way with closest, to check if a click is outside of an Element:

```
$(document).click(function(event) { 
  if(!$(event.target).closest("#wrapper").length) {
    console.log($(event.target))
    console.log("click outside of #wrapper");
  }
});

$("#remove-me").click(function(){
  $(this).remove();
  console.log("remove me clicked");
});

$("#click-me").click(function(){
  console.log("click clicked");
});

<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="remove-me">click me to remove from dom</div>
  <div id="click-me">click me</div>
</div>
```

But if i click `#remove-me`, the `div` gets removed from the DOM - its now somewhere in space - and it wont find any `closest()`. The suprising thing is that the `document` listener still gets the click AND the element, although its not in the DOM anymore...

How would i properly find a way, if this `div` is inside of my wrapper. 
Is this a jQuery Problem or is there a pure Javascript way?
Why is the `$(document).click()` listener still trigger on the removed element?

One way i found out to check if the `div` has no `parent()`...

Codepen Example: http://codepen.io/urtopal/pen/BLJgrQ

---

Summary/Question:

1. Why is an listener on an removed Element still triggered(example above "click outside of #wrapper" should not be executed if `#remove-me` is clicked)?
2. How to resolve this? No trigger at all / or how to check if removed?

Comment: Please put the relevant code (HTML) in the question.

Comment: I'm unclear what you're asking. When you `remove()` `#remove` it's gone forever. That click handler will never execute again.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking, once remove-me is gone, you will only get the click-me trigger since if you clicked inside the wrapper (unless you click on the white space outside of wrapper), there is no wrapper outside of the wrapper so the document binding won't fire. What are you trying to do? Clarify exactly what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @squint i added the HTML

Comment: @Rory-McCrossan the $(document).click() catched the remove click on "#remove-me" after it got removed(). This is why i was wondering(a click on a non existing element??). Why is this happening? How to prevent?

Comment: So you were wondering why on the *same* click that event was fired on the `document`? That was the confusing part of your question for me. It sounded like you were saying `remove-me` was somehow responding to later clicks.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try to `return false;` on the end of the `'click'` handler, it will prevent the event from bubbling up the DOM, and also stop other bound handlers from executing:

```
$("#remove-me").click(function(){
  $(this).remove();
  console.log("remove me clicked");
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks that helped. The click wont bubble along anymore so nothing else will get triggered..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$(document).click(function(event) { 
  if($(event.target).prop("tagName").toLowerCase() == "html") {
    console.log("click outside of #wrapper");
  }
});
                  
$("#remove-me").click(function(){
  $(this).remove();
  console.log("remove me clicked");
});

$("#click-me").click(function(){
  console.log("click clicked");
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="remove-me">click me to remove from dom</div>
  <div id="click-me">click me</div>
</div>
```